# How to get a dump of all weblogic mbeans, their attributes,values for a domain using wlst

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, wlst

I need to search all mbean attributes values for a particular string in all mbeans of a domain. Is it possible to take a dump of all the mbeans,their attributes, and the values for a domain using wlst or jython or python.

WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.6.0

Already tried find('string') but it searches for attributes and not values.